Etching on Vanity Top
My wife & I have twin bathroom vanities with the same tops. I don't know what material is used, but it is solid white and is very hard, so is not something like Corian. Marble, perhaps? Her vanity has what appears to be etching from some chemical. I tried using a buffing wheel with red (and then black) rouge, but it isn't buffing out this surface damage (at least not after 20 minutes). Does anyone have suggestions as to how to identify this material, what is causing the damage, and how to restore its shine?

possibly nail polish remover that contains acetone ... to answer your question, test all items that your wife uses on another part of the countertop

acetone will not attack marble but it's possible that there is a coating on the remainder of the top that has been stripped from the blemished location.

Odds are it's a cultured marble.  What is this "rouge" you mention?

"White rouge" is the buffing compound I was using. The others I have are brown "Tripoli" and black "Emery." I will look into polishing or coating cultured marble.

I found our order for these. It is "engineered marble." I sanded the deeper parts with wet 600 and then used MB-11 Etch Remover and it looks a lot better. I will finish with a sealer next.
